# C++/Cli System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was clos ed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, visual-c++, ssl-certificate, remote-server

I'm using Visual C++/cli to call a web service. I need to do validate the SSL certificates. I have given below my code and give me any resolution for this issue. I am struggling for this issue from last two weeks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#using <System.dll>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Net::Security;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography::X509Certificates;

static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
        Object^ sender,
        X509Certificate^ certificate,
        X509Chain^ chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{                    HttpWebRequest^ request = dynamic_cast<HttpWebRequest^>(WebRequest::Create("https://example.com/plugin?plugin=ipru&"));
                request->Method = "POST";
                char temReq[1024];
                memset(temReq, 0x00, sizeof(temReq));
                strcpy(temReq,"method=");
                strcat(temReq, "requestFromMPOSSDK");
                strcat(temReq, "&data=");
                strcat(temReq, "postdata");
                strcat(temReq, "&mid=");
                strcat(temReq,  "153225235235");
                strcat(temReq, "&tid=");
                strcat(temReq,  "64643463");
                strcat(temReq, "&amount=");
                strcat(temReq,  "2");
                strcat(temReq, "&requestType=");
                strcat(temReq,  "54545");
                strcat(temReq,"");


                String^ postData = gcnew System::String(temReq);
                printf(temReq);

                ASCIIEncoding^ encoding = gcnew ASCIIEncoding;
                array<Byte>^ byte1 = encoding->GetBytes(postData);
                request->ContentType = "text/plain";



                request->ContentLength = byte1->Length;
                Stream^ newStream = request->GetRequestStream();


                newStream->Write( byte1, 0, byte1->Length);
            try {

                request->Credentials = CredentialCache::DefaultCredentials;

                System::Net::Security::RemoteCertificateValidationCallback^ clb = gcnew RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
                System::Net::ServicePointManager::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = clb;



                HttpWebResponse^ response = dynamic_cast<HttpWebResponse^>(request->GetResponse());


                Console::WriteLine("Content length is {0}", response->ContentLength);
                Console::WriteLine("Content type is {0}", response->ContentType );

                Stream^ receiveStream = response->GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader^ readStream = gcnew StreamReader( receiveStream,Encoding::UTF8 );
                Console::WriteLine( "Response received." );
                Console::WriteLine( readStream->ReadToEnd() );
                response->Close();
                readStream->Close();
                return S_OK;
         }
         catch(UnauthorizedAccessException^ e) {
             Console::Write("retrying in 1 sec");

         }


}
```